# Java - Can you use String for switch?

Tags: java, switch-statement, case

I am using switch{case ()} with String in java, and so far it seems to be working perfectly. But I want to confirm before continuing too much; is this safe?

I mean, I know that I should not be doing if ("hi" == "hi"), but should be doing "hi".equals ("hi") because String refers to a reference point...

I am not too sure how switch works, and I have not been able to confirm from any of my sources...

Thank you!!

Comment: yes and no, depending on the java version (1.7 up)

Comment: What do you mean by java version?

Comment: @Orange: Um, the version of the Java language you're using...

Comment: So if I have java later than version 7, my method should be safe right?

Comment: Indeed, and note that Java is clever enough to compare the string *contents*, not the *references*.

Comment: Not only later, including Java 1.7 & above @Orange

Comment: Hint: please understand that this is a really really basic question. For such things, try to do **prior research** before dropping a question here. SO is **not** about asking and answering the same questions over and and over and over again.

Comment: The linked duplicate IMHO does not give a satisfying answer to this question as all answers to that question use pre-Java 7 language features and no explanations for "string in switch" are given.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11) (emphasis mine):

> If one of the case constants **is equal to the value of the expression**, then we say that the case matches, and all statements after the matching case label in the switch block, if any, are executed in sequence.

This implies that the switch case is evaluated using `equals`, not `==`.